# How to integrate azure-map in iOS Application

Tags: azure, azure-maps

We are planning to move from Google Map to Azure Map.But while going through microsoft document ,I could see there is no SDK for iOS app for Azure Map.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-maps/migrate-from-google-maps

Is this true even now as the document got updated Dec 2019.

Comment: I do not think SDK for iOS is available as of yet. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-mobility-service-for-azure-maps-sdks-updates-and-more/. You can ask the team and provide them feedback from here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps.

Answer (score 1):

iOS SDK for Azure Maps is not yet available, but planned.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an SDK now, see the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/quick-ios-app).