# Using Azure Maps with React Native

Tags: react-native, azure-maps

I have to build a mobile application that would work with both Android and iOS, so that's why I'm not using the Azure Maps Android SDK.

So I just wanna know if it is possible to use the Azure maps in React Native. I've tried with this repo: `https://github.com/WiredSolutions/react-azure-maps` which is a react wrapper for the Azure Maps. This repo is working perfectly on the web app, using react, but it doesn't seem to work on the mobile app, because when I'm trying to import these packages:

`import {AzureMap, AzureMapsProvider, IAzureMapOptions} from 'react-azure-maps';`

`import {AuthenticationType} from 'azure-maps-control';`

it's throwing an `Cannot create URL for blob!` exception in the `react-azure-maps.umd.js` and in the `atlas.min.js` files.

The version installed in package.json are:

```
    "azure-maps-control": "^2.0.31",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-azure-maps": "^0.1.4",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
```

Comment: It might be better to raise this as an issue/question on that open source project.

Comment: I did that, and for that specific open source project, the answer is no, it can't be used for mobile applications. But my question is still not answered, is there no way of using Azure maps with React native?

Comment: You need to create a native bridge. React and React Native use different primitives. (DOM VS Native Components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem yet, because, as the other answers said, iOS is not supported. Also, there are no libraries for react native that are supporting Azure Maps.

My workaround was to use React Native Maps as the map provider, and just do a backend call to the Azure Maps route provider.

In this way, I just draw the route provided by Azure Maps on the React Native Map.

Hopefully this will help some other people that are trying to use Azure Maps.

Comment: could you share some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems, that iOS is not yet supported.  [How to integrate azure-map in iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915559/how-to-integrate-azure-map-in-ios-application)

If MS will not publish library for React Native, you would need to create RN wrapper by yourself.

Comment: it is better to poste this as comment